# Compare date from database using parameters

Tags: c#, ms-access, datetime, parameters, date-format

```
string queryString = "SELECT SUM(skupaj_kalorij)as Skupaj_Kalorij  "
                + "FROM (obroki_save LEFT JOIN users ON obroki_save.ID_uporabnika=users.ID)"
                + "WHERE (users.ID= " + a.ToString() + ") AND (obroki_save.datum= @datum)";

            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(queryString,database))                                    
                {
                    DateTime datum = DateTime.Today;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datum", datum);
                }
            loadDataGrid2(queryString);
```

I tried now with parameters. But i don't really know how to do it correctly. I tried like this, but the parameter datum doesn't get any value(according to c#).

Comment: what error? also where are you comparing a date, I can see you create date but not use it?

Comment: The error may be that ToShortDateString returns the date in a format that SQL does not recognizes. (It is generally better to use parameters to pass parameters in a query.) But without indication of what error actually occurred, it's hard to tell if the cause of the error is this or something entirely different.

Comment: numbers syntax error in query command in the whole where statement(users.id=1 AND obroki_save.datum=20.5.2010)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please try this :

```
database = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
                database.Open();
                date = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
                string queryString = "SELECT SUM(skupaj_kalorij)as Skupaj_Kalorij  "
                    + "FROM (obroki_save LEFT JOIN users ON obroki_save.ID_uporabnika=users.ID)" 
                    + "WHERE users.ID= " + a.ToString()+" AND obroki_save.datum= '" +DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString() + "'";
                loadDataGrid2(queryString);
```

when you use with Date, you must write like this

```
select * from table where date = '@date'
```

not like

```
select * from table where date = @date
```

Comment: but man. I don't get no results now.... Couse i changed the datatype from date to text in the database. Now i changed it back to date/time and i get an error that theres a wrong data type in the Conditional statement.

Comment: use DateTime.Now.ToString(); instead of DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();

Comment: I changed the commas on the top (doesn't matter how they're called right now :D), so i get an messege that there's an syntax error in the  number somewhere in the where statement

Answer (score 1):

While it's usually useful to post the error, I'd hazard a guess and say that you're getting a conversion error with your date.

You should really look at parameterising your queries...

You should read this: http://www.aspnet101.com/2007/03/parameterized-queries-in-asp-net/

And if you can't be bothered reading that, then try  changing your 'a' variable to '1; DROP TABLE obroki; --' (but only after you back up your database).

Comment: Did you try the # delimiter for the date?

Comment: BTW, Jet/ACE is not vulnerable to that particular SQL injection vulnerability, because it doesn't execute but one SQL statement at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to write your SQL string in the SQL dialect of the database you're using. In Jet/ACE SQL (what's used by Access), the delimiter for date values is #, so you'd need this:

```
  obroki_save.datum= #" +DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString() + "#"
```

Of course, some data interface libraries translate these things for you, so that may not be the problem here.